# Displaying 2 Chart items in the same chart

Tags: excel, excel-charts

How can I get this chart to have the quantity of `10` inside the bar of the bar chart and outside of the X-axis?[image: this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Played around for a while and figured it out.

1. Move quantity to VALUES
2. Select the bar and make it a secondary axis.
3. Set it to 'no fill'
4. Show it's data label and display at the bottom.